# Combobox tabindex doesn´t work

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, tabindex

I am developing a `windows mobile aplication.`

One of my 5 `forms` is full of `Combo and Textboxes:`

When my user uses the `tab key`, my cursor shoulda be on my first `combobox (cmbCia)` (but it goes to the last `(cmbPrice))`, when the user press the `tab key` again, my cursor shoulda go to the second `Combo (cmbNumAc)`, but it goes to the `fourth (cmbPlace)`... I have 9 items

I set my `Combo` and `Textboxes` with the `tabindex` on my `GUI` by right click and properties:

```
 - cmbCia's tabindex = 1
 -  cmbNumAc's  tabindex = 2
 ... 
 - cmbTxr's tabindex  = 9
```

I saw pages like: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6101447/how-to-disable-tabindex,) [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11052265/tabindex-does-not-work-correctly) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16063353/tab-index-does-not-work-with-controls-in-panels) but they didn´t help me

**Any idea about what could I do?**

Comment: Which compact-framework do you use, or which Visual Studio?